# dragging to populate cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am aware that you can fill the cells in Excel as a series by dragging the square in the bottom right corner.

for example typing "1" in Cell "A1" and dragging the box down to "A10" will give you a series from 1 to 10 in those cells.

I want to know if it is possible to have the increments in which it populates to go up in twos or fours...

an example of this would be dragging down from "A1" to "A10" as before but having say 1 3 5 7 9 and so on in the cells just by dragging the box in the bottom right corner.

Is there a way to make this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to type the first 2 or 3 numbers in and then select all of them and then drag down. eg. Type 2 4 and then drag and you will get 2 4 6 8 10 etc...

Comment: Ah I just that minute tried it and it seems to do what I need its for a user of mine that is in control of many stock numbers consisting of 6 digits that go up in increments of 2's and 3's and so on this would work for say 555444, 555446 and so on?

Comment: Yes that will work. It doesn't matter were you start you can even do things like 2 4 8 16 etc... or 200 800 3200 etc...

Answer (score 2):

Type your “1”. 
Drag the square (I believe that it’s called the “fill handle”)
***with the right mouse button***. 
When you release the button, you’ll get this menu:

[image]

Select “Series…”.  You’ll get this dialog box:

[image]

Set “Step value” to 2, and there you go:

[image]